# Rails form redirect renders in console only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using Rails 5.1 and want to include a search field in my website, so I have added a small form with "form_with". In my server log claims that all is rendered as expected but the page /products does not load anyway. Instead the page does not react to "Submit":

```html
 Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (24.5ms)
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_with(url: products_path, method: 'get') do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :q, 'Search for:' %>
  <%= form.text_field :q, id: 'q', value: params[:q] %>
  <%= form.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

And this is my complete server log, just in case it helps.

```
Started GET "/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=x&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-09 09:39:37 +0200
Processing by ProductsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"x", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Rendered collection of products/_product.html.erb [5 times] (2.8ms)
  Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (24.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 98ms (Views: 78.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

The search field is on a different page than products/index.html.erb. But nevertheless my server says that it is "rendered". Why am I not redirected to it then?

Comment: What's in your controller?

Comment: Actually I just fixed it. I added local: true to form_with. Now it works. But I am not sure why it needs to be told that.

Comment: I saw this `:local - By default form submits are remote and unobstrusive XHRs. Disable remote submits with local: true`, take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)